# How to Implement this Static Method in a Class with Generics

Tags: java

In my team, we are trying to remove the Guava library and we want to implement a helper class to perform some functions of the Guava Table class. I came up with the Class below. My mentor wants me to make this class generic and he expects a static '.of()' method the same way that a Map has a static 'of()' method.

Is this possible? how can I implement it? Or should I tell him I cannot have both a generic class and a static method.

In the of() method I get the compilation error '.this cannot be referenced from a static context'.

```
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;

public class RowColumnMap<R, C, V> {

    private final LinkedHashMap<R, Map<C, V>> linkedHashMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();

    public RowColumnMap(Map<R, Map<C, V>> original) {
        this.linkedHashMap.putAll(original);
    }

    public RowColumnMap() {}

    public Map<R, Map<C, V>> get() {
        return linkedHashMap;
    }

    public static RowColumnMap<R, C, V> of(R rowKey, C columnKey, V value) {
        return new RowColumnMap<>(Map.of(rowKey, Map.of(columnKey, value)));
    }
```

Comment: `public static <R, C, V> RowColumnMap<R, C, V> of(...) { ... }`

Comment: Just curious, why removing Guava? It's a great library, and you're unlikely to do better if you try. Sometimes it's good to be frugal in terms of dependencies, but once it's already in your dependency graph I'd say Guava is something you can make good use.

Comment: Note that `get` returns the field `linkedHashMap`, which is mutable. Someone calling `rowColumnMap.get()` and then modifying the hashmap also causes the contents of `rowColumnMap` to be changed! You are better off making `RowColumnMap` [*immutable*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object). A solution may be to change `get()` to return a [*defensive copy*](https://java-journal.blogspot.com/2011/01/defensive-copy-part-1-problem-and.html) instead.

Comment: @Dici We would get regular warnings that most of our used Guava classes and methods can be replaced with Java internals. You might be wondering why I made a new class then. Well, I wanted some help visualising how to replace Table.rowMap() and Table.cellSet(). But I didn't really need to make a separate class.

Comment: Yeah the problem is that Java guys didn't go far enough... in my opinion they should just have copied Guava collections, but they didn't include immutable builders and their immutable collections are not ordered like Guava's. That's a shame ^^ Thanks for explaining your reasons

Answer (score 1):

You can provide a *method* with type parameters:

```java
public static <R, C, V> RowColumnMap<R, C, V> of(R rowKey, C columnKey, V value) {
    return new RowColumnMap<>(Map.of(rowKey, Map.of(columnKey, value)));
}
```

The type parameters for the method are written right in front of the return type.

Answer (score 1):

Static methods do not have access to the type parameters of the class they are in. So if you write:

```
public class RowColumnMap<R, C, V> { ... }
```

then the type parameters `R`, `C` and `V` are not accessible to any static methods in the class. This means that if you write this:

```
public static RowColumnMap<R, C, V> of(R rowKey, C columnKey, V value)
```

then `R`, `C` and `V` do **not** refer to the type parameters of the class - instead, Java is going to look for concrete types with these names, and will complain that they are not found.

You can give the static method its own type parameters:

```
public static <R, C, V> RowColumnMap<R, C, V> of(R rowKey, C columnKey, V value)
```

Note that the type parameters of the static method are *not* the same ones as the type parameters of the class. In this case we've given them the same names `R`, `C` and `V` but they are separate from the type parameters on the class. We could just as well have given them other names, to make this clear:

```
public class RowColumnMap<R, C, V> {
    // ...

    public static <X, Y, Z> RowColumnMap<X, Y, Z> of(X rowKey, Y columnKey, Z value) {
        return new RowColumnMap<>(Map.of(rowKey, Map.of(columnKey, value)));
    }
}
```